# Как взять данные с массива?

Tags: php, массивы, curl

Делаю запрос на api
получаю ответ
﻿

```
{
"list": [
{
"name1": "1111",
"name12": "",
"name113": "2222",
"name1134": "",
{
"name1": "1111231231",
"name12": "4545454",
"name113": "2123222",
"name1134": "5454545",
}
```

Не могу взять данные через
$data['list'][0]['name1'];
выводит просто �
Если пытаюсь задекодить в decode_json - ничего не выводит массив

вот код -

```
<?PHP
$curlHandler = curl_init();

$userName = '.xxxxx';
$password = 'xxx';

curl_setopt_array($curlHandler, [
    CURLOPT_URL => 'xxxx',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,

    CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_BASIC,
    CURLOPT_USERPWD => $userName . ':' . $password,
]);

$response = curl_exec($curlHandler);
curl_close($curlHandler);
echo "<PRE>";
print_r($response,true) // ничего не выводит
print_r($response)// выводит массив который сверху
print_r($response['list'][0]['name1']; // выводит�
echo "<PRE>";
```

Comment: второй параметр в print_r говори что надо вывод вернуть, а не вывести. так что не удивительно, что он ничего не выводит. А вот если делаете просто json_decode, вот  тут как раз и пригодится второй параметр, который вернет ассоциативные массивы а не объект, вы же обращаетесь к результату как к массиву, что при простом декоде выведет нотисов

Comment: Так какое решение проблемы можно предложить*?

Comment: @ArcWarden Я вам 26 минут назад в комментарии написал (и скопировал его же  в ответ)  какое решение...... + сам json_decode

Answer (score 1):

Данные в формате json, а пытаетесь работать с массивом. Вас не смущает?

Используйте **[json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php)**

```
$data = json_decode($response, true);
```

---

Также, у вас не валидный объект. один из элементов не закрыт `}`,  да и сам массив тоже `]` ... да и финальной `}` тоже нет.. Так что для начала сформируйте валидный json

Comment: Когда пытаюсь за декодить массив,он ничего не выдаёт мне.

Comment: @ArcWarden у вас не валидный объект. один из элементов не закрыт `}` . да и сам массив тоже `]` ... да и финальной `}`  тоже ..... так что для начала валидный json отправьте